# Unable to type spaces in "multiline" of Pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to sanitize input typed in `sg.Multiline`, and I have this:

```py
def sanitize_query(window: sg.Window, values: dict):
    # Sanitize query: replace/remove/escape all unallowed characters in command-line
    # Spaces are allowed in query

    query = values['-INPUT-QUERY-']

    sanitized_query = query

    # Replace newline with space
    if "\n" in query:
        sanitized_query = query.replace("\n", " ")
    # Replace double quote with single quote
    if "\"" in query:
        sanitized_query = query.replace("\"", "'")
    # Replace backslash with double backslash
    if "\\" in query:
        sanitized_query = query.replace("\\", "\\\\")

    # Update query in GUI
    window['-INPUT-QUERY-'](sanitized_query)
    values.update({'-INPUT-QUERY-': sanitized_query})

# ... (in event loop)
# Input changed
if '-INPUT-' in event:
    # Sanitize query
    if event == '-INPUT-QUERY-':
        sanitize_query(window=window, values=values)
```

However, this function will cause me be unable to type any spaces in query. Why is that so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the default option `rstrip=True`, you will get `rstrip` content of the `Multiline` element, like `space` typed.

To use the option `rstrip=False`, for your case, you need to be handle the condition - there's always one `\n` added by tkinter for the Text widget (Multiline element in PySimpleGUI).

Now, what you can do is to

- Set `rstrip=False` in Multiline element.
- Get the content of Multiline element by `values['-INPUT-QUERY-'][:-1]`

Also, another issue here, the input cursor will be always moved to the end of content after you update the content of Multiline. For example, arrow key not work, also something like this.

To work all fine in your case, the only way is to use `element.widget` to call tkinter method to update only what typed when necessary, and set the correct position of input cursor.

Comment: Thank you! BTW: by "Set `rstrip=True` in Multiline element", I think you meant `rstrip=False`? (I set it to false and change `query = values['-INPUT-QUERY-']` to `query = values['-INPUT-QUERY-'][:-1]` and it works.)

Comment: Updated - Set `rstrip=False` in Multiline element.